# Jensen's inequality for proving $E\left[\frac1X\right]\ge \frac1{E[X]}$ where $P(X\leq 0) = 0$

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Let $X$ be a positive random variable, i.e., $P(X\leq 0) = 0$. Argue that, 
$$E\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big] \geq \frac{1}{E\Big[X\Big]}$$

Since Jensen's Inequality is $\phi(E[X]) \leq E[\phi(X)]$, where $\phi$ is convex, is the question as simple as letting $\phi(X) = \frac{1}{X}$?

Comment: Yes, it is really that simple!

Comment: Would one have to first show that $\phi(X) = \frac{1}{X}$ is convex?

Comment: It is convex because the second derivative $\frac 2 {x^{3}}$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$.